# What does ":" mean in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm new to Lua and I have work on project, I have an issue unterstanding what ":" I didn't found it on the manual for example how should interpret this piece of code :

```
res:template{
        main = 'functionform.html',
        functionjs = '_functionform.js',
        functionform = '_functionform.html'
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the manual in [section 2.5.8](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.8):

> A function call in Lua has the following syntax:
>
> functioncall ::= prefixexp args
>
> In a function call, first prefixexp and args are evaluated. If the
>   value of prefixexp has type function, then this function is called
>   with the given arguments. Otherwise, the prefixexp "call" metamethod
>   is called, having as first parameter the value of prefixexp, followed
>   by the original call arguments (see §2.8).
>
> The form
>
> functioncall ::= prefixexp `:´ Name args
>
> can be used to call "methods". A call v:name(args) is syntactic sugar
>   for v.name(v,args), except that v is evaluated only once.

So `res:template{}` is the same as `res.template(res, {})`.

Answer (score 7):

The colon operator<sup>[PIL](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html)</sup> in Lua is a little syntatic sugar. It's used in object oriented Lua, to make a regular function call look more like a method call. What it does is pass the object as the `self` parameter when you call a function. Take this example:

```
a.myFunction(a, 'foo')
```

It's equivalent to:

```
a:myFunction('foo')
```

In your example, the method call is omiting the parentheses because its only argument is a table<sup>[PIL](http://www.lua.org/pil/5.html)</sup>, so your function call without the colon operator would be somthing like:

```
res.template(res, {
        main = 'functionform.html',
        functionjs = '_functionform.js',
        functionform = '_functionform.html'
    })
```

So as you can see, this little syntatic sugar is pretty handy

Answer (score 3):

The colon operator adds an additional 'hidden' parameter in method definition and argument in method call. (e.g. this / self)

http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html

So a call to your template function provides the hidden argument 'self' through which you can access the object on which the function is defined.