# Lua functions with colon

Tags: lua

I am having a problem fully understanding the lua syntax so while this answer may be simple perhaps some authorative references will help me and others further learn.

```
function blah()
```

and

```
function classname:blah()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does ":" mean in Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27110276/what-does-mean-in-lua)

Comment: I think this question could be improved if it was edited to contain a question. :-)

Answer (score 30):

Aubergine18's post covers the answer, but I'll explain from first principles to provide further clarification.

In Lua, functions are values, just like strings or numbers. This expression:

```
function() end
```

Creates a function value. You can assign this to a variable, just as you would any other value:

```
foo = function() end
```

Lua provides various short-cut syntaxes, also called "syntax sugar", for working with function values. The first is this:

```
function foo() end
```

This is exactly equivalent to:

```
foo = function() end
```

The other is:

```
function bar.foo() end
```

Which is exactly equivalent to:

```
bar.foo = function() end
```

In this example, `bar` is a table, `foo` is a key in that table, and the function value we created is the value assigned to that key.

Note that if you *call* foo:

```
bar.foo()
```

The function has no way of knowing that it was stored in the table `bar` using the key `foo`. If you want to treat that function as a *method* on the object `bar`, you need to provide it access to `bar` in some way. This is typically done by passing `bar` as the first parameter. By convention in Lua this parameter is named `self`:

```
function bar.foo(self) end

bar.foo(bar)
```

As a shortcut for this convention, Lua provides the following syntax sugar via the `:` operator:

```
function bar:foo() end

bar:foo()
```

This is exactly equivalent to the previous code.

Comment: Minor correction in the last code sample above... should be __bar:foo()__ (the colon required to make Lua automatically pass 'bar' as first parameter to 'foo' function.

Comment: Great explanation. One question: if I call `bar:foo()` given that `bar` is silently passed into the method body, how do I call on `bar`? Is it actually `self`?

Comment: @IAbstract Yes. `function bar:foo() end` is literally translated into `function bar.foo(self) end`, so `foo` has a first parameter named `self` no matter what other parameters you do (or don't) give it.  `bar:foo()` is literally translated into `bar.foo(bar)`, so inside of `foo`, `self` will contain `bar`.

Answer (score 7):

When you call a function using colon notation, like this:

```
foo:bar()
```

Lua treats it like this behind the scenes:

```
foo.bar(foo)
```

If you define your function using dot notation, you'll have to manually specify the 'self' argument:

```
function foo.bar(self) ... end
```

However if you use colon notation, Lua will add an invisible 'self' parameter for you:

```
function foo:bar() ... end
```

Even though you don't see the self argument, it's there behind the scenes.

Basically colon notation is just a way to make your code look cleaner.

See also: [Lua: colon notation, 'self' and function definition vs. call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32080972/lua-colon-notation-self-and-function-definition-vs-call)

Comment: How come some functions do not have foo at all and they just put bar? What does that then mean? Also self is referring to an instance of the class? I am prettty much new to Lua. Why do I need self?

Comment: If you have foo.bar() or foo:bar() then the function is just a property on the 'foo' table. It doesn't really matter where you put functions...

They can be locally defined __local function bar() ... end__, globally defined __function bar() ... end__ or defined as a property of a table, __function foo.bar() ... end__.

The __self__ stuff isn't needed, unless you need it heh. If you don't need a reference to the table or object your function is a property of, then you don't need to use the colon notation or self.